# Java applet socket server permissions

Tags: java, security, sockets, applet

- I want to make a Java applet, which functions as a socket *server* (local network ips, or 127 range is fine).
- I want this applet to run in a webpage.
- the browser can ideally load the webpage from the file system (file://...), but I could install an HTTP server if required.
- The applet will need to be able to interact with JavaScript.

I'm having trouble wading through all the docs. Is the above possible? I'm not familiar with java's security model. If I need to sign the applet, or set some special security or configuration settings, that's fine.

edit-
In case anyones curious, the applet does very little. I just want to use it as a bridge so that another program running on the local computer can communicate via sockets. That program supplies values, which javascript will use to update the ui in real time. The ui is complicated, and building it in html/javascript will be a huge time saver. I'd prefer the applet function as the socket server opposed to a socket client, because otherwise then I need to write a seperate program to act as a server in between the applet and the other program.

Comment: What does the applet do, and why the JS interaction?

Comment: I think that using an embedded applet because HTML/JS is faster for you to develop is a wrong direction.  It will cause a lot of head-aches with deployment and maintenance - less time to create the GUI, with the downside of more time deploying/maintaining.  What actual GUI elements does it need?

Comment: deployment and maintenence aren't significant considerations here. This is for personal use by me and my brother, which is why tweaking security settings(if possible) are ok. my personal productivity writing the frontend in html/js opposed to java is probably 20-30x greater for this project, and so large sacrifices are quite warranted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the above possible?

Sure. If you control the security/policy files for that applet & the firewall, it is a single browser deal, it should be doable. You might need to wrap some of the applet methods in a `PrivilegedAction` if called from JS.

Comment: just wanted to follow up that this did work on windows(i wrapped in a PrivilegedAction), although on linux it acted like my edits to the policy file weren't present. I'm reasonably sure the correct policy file was edited, as it's location was found via the java console in the browser. oh well. I just installed a webserver and requested the file via http instead of loading it through the file:// protocol so that the policy edits arent neccesary, and all is good in the hood now.